# How to use modules alias in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

i've thought that using path & basePath in tsconfig allow aliases, but no.

```js
"moduleResolution": "node",
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "@api/*": ["api/*"]
},
```

```js
import routes from '@api/routes'; // pjroot/src/api/routes.ts (VS Code sees this file)
```

Error: Cannot find module '@api/routes'

when i compile project, i see that aliases @api don't replace to paths, why ?
i don't want use third party modules like modulesAlias etc for that simple task.

For what are exists aliases in config ? if they are not replace with real paths during compilation?

Answer (score 0):

No Way.
path aliases intended for modules bandler like webpack.

[typescript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26722#issuecomment-580975983)

you should use modules like module-alias etc.